# How to update excel metadata using java

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I am trying to update excel metadata in java using apache POI. Input file is large containing 8K columns and 600 rows. I am using below code

```
    OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("path for input"));
    POIXMLProperties props = new POIXMLProperties(pkg);
    props.getCoreProperties().setTitle("Test Title");

    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("path for output");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    wb.write(bos);
    fos.close();
```

Above code is throwing me Out Of memory exception as below.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3414)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1272)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1259)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.WorksheetDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:227)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:219)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.parseSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:452)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:417)
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:184)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:286)
```

Could you please help to overcome this issue for updating excel properties ?

Comment: If you just want to save the properties, why are you loading the workbook streams just to save? Why not save the OPC layer directly?

Comment: Thank you .. i invoked pkg.close() immediately after changing the title. It worked. Also removed  code that loads the workbook streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer....

If you're just changing the OPC level metadata, there's no need to load the file up in the `XSSF` layer at any point. You'd only need to do that if you also wanted to change the spreadsheet contents eg cells

Your code can be as simple as

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("path for input"));
POIXMLProperties props = new POIXMLProperties(pkg);
props.getCoreProperties().setTitle("Test Title");
props.commit();
pkg.close();
```